# Multiple inputs : input string with succeeding spaces and then an integer in C++

Tags: c++, string, user-input

Not able to give input in the following format

```
1                //number of test case
"some string   " //string with succeeding spaces
13               //some integer
```

Below is the code:

```
int main(void){
    int i, j;
    int act_size;
    int tc;
    cin>>tc;
    std::string inp;
    while(tc--){
        getline(cin, inp);
        cin>>act_size;
        //inp = "Mr John Smith    ";
        //act_size = 13;
        printNewString(inp, act_size);
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it skips over the `act_size` input and program exits without any output. But if I hard code the values, it works fine.

Comment: `cin>>tc;` attempts to read an `int` that is not in the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle wrong data type input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349857/how-to-handle-wrong-data-type-input)

Comment: @tobi303 Sorry, I forgot to mention test case input in the format. The error which I am discussing has occurred with the updated input format.

Comment: see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in the Notes section.

Comment: `cin` does not consume the `\n`, so `getline` reads only that, there are also dupes on that