# Why does an extremely large value cause this code to repeat infinitely?

Tags: c++

```
int n;  

do
{
    cout << "What height should the pyramid be? ";
    cin >> n;
} while (n <= 1 || n > 23);
```

So as you can see it should only take values between 0 and 24, which works fine. If you put in an extremely large value though, it repeats infinitely. Is there a way to safeguard against abusing that at the input stage?

(side note, anyone know why "n < 0" allows 0 as a value in this instance?)

Comment: `(...) & cin` should break it, but you still do not have correct `n`.

Comment: You omitted the datatype (`int`, `long`, &c) of `n` from your question.

Comment: `std::cin` is pretty weird (it uses bad flags rather than exceptions... for speed reasons?). [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349857/how-to-handle-wrong-data-type-input)

Comment: Thank you for linking that question, I mustn't have looked as hard as I thought... Cheers for the quick and helpful comments all!

Comment: @MateenUlhaq you can [turn on exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions), though

Comment: Can you provide an example of an "extremely large value"?  I am assuming that the answer provided below is correct but it would good to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `failbit` of `cin` will be set if the input number is too large to be stored in an `int`, then following `cin >> n` will always fail. You can use `cin.clear()` to clear the `failbit` before `cin >> n`:

```
int n;  

do
{
    cin.clear();  // <-----
    cout << "What height should the pyramid be? ";
    cin >> n;
} while (n <= 1 || n > 23);
```