# C++ not taking input inside a procedure with cin>>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, input, procedure, cin

So I have been writing a procedure, inside which I need to take input of two variables, int data and int index. Inside my main function, I have a while loop which takes input until a non integer value is entered.

**The problem:**
When I call the procedure before the while loop inside the main function, everything works fine. However, when I call the procedure after the while loop, the console does not ask me for inputting int data and int index. I don't understand why?

**What do I know so far and what I have tried:**
I have faced a similar problem with the getline() function for strings, and I was able to solve it with cin.ignore(), however, I cannot solve this one with cin.ignore(). I read quite a lot of related posts, but still can't figure it out.

**My code**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void proced() {
    int data, index;
    cin >> data >> index;
    cout << "this is data: " << data << endl;
    cout << "this is index: " << index << endl;
}
int main() {
    int temp;
    int dance=0;
    while (cin >> temp) {
        dance = temp;
    }
    cout << "this is dance: " <<dance<< endl;
    proced();
}
```

**output when procedure is called after while loop**

input: 1 2 3 4 5^Z
output:
this is dance: 5

this is data: -858993460

this is index: -858993460
**output when procedure is called before while loop**

input: 1 2 3 4 5^Z
output:
this is data: 1

this is index: 2

this is dance: 5

Ps. I am coding in visual studio 2019

Comment: Ask yourself what will be in `cin` when you finish the `while(cin >> temp) {` loop.

Comment: If the `while()` loops ends, `std::cin()` is in failed state, you have to call `std::cin.clear()` and consume the excess characters, before you proceed.

Comment: @scohe001 I believe cin will have ^z, but Idk how to get rid of that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I already tried cin.clear(), it didn't seem to work. Can you be more detailed please?

Comment: @YahyaAbdulMajeed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it

Answer (score 0):

**1.** case with `proced()` after `while`

`cin.ignore()` is right way to go, you just might missed something. Here's my understanding and solution:

The `while (cin >> temp) {`  in your code breaks not because of `eof` but because of `fail`. It's easy to check by slightly modifying your code:

```
    while ( !cin.eof() ) {
        cin >> temp;
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear(); // clear fail flag
            cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()); // ignore the rest in input
            break;
        }
        dance = temp;
    }
```

When you debug the input `1 2 3 4 5^Z` it will go inside `fail` enclose.
Now to make `cin` process next input correctly the fail flag should be cleared and failed data ignored, which is done by code inside `if(cin.fail())`

The call `cin.rdbuf()->inavail()` in your test is equal to `1` which is length of faulty input `^Z`.

**2.** case with `proced()` before `while` :

First 2 numbers go to `data` and `index` then the `while` executes and reach the `fail()` part.

Results are different but logic is same.

These StackOverflow posts have a lot of information related to your issue:

[How to handle wrong data type input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349857/how-to-handle-wrong-data-type-input)

[How to test whether stringstream operator>> has parsed a bad type and skip it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it)

[How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. This is what I needed.